# Wordpress HttpWebrequest vb.net

Tags: vb.net, wordpress, cookies, httpwebrequest, system.net.httpwebrequest

I am trying to code some self bot to do some stuff for me on my self hosted wordpress blogs, so I managed to login successfully using webrequests had some problems but solved them.
But now I'm trying to go to permalinks page for example to get some data but when Im trying to do it using the login cookie it just redirects me back to login page like I'm not using the login cookie.

So basically this is the login function:

```
 cleanurl = TextBox3.Text
    logincookie = New CookieContainer

    Dim url As String = cleanurl & "/wp-login.php"
    Dim postreq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
    Dim cookies As New CookieContainer

    postreq.CookieContainer = cookies
    postreq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0b6pre) Gecko/20100903 Firefox/4.0b6pre"
    postreq.KeepAlive = True
    postreq.Timeout = 120000
    postreq.Method = "POST"
    postreq.Referer = url

    postreq.AllowAutoRedirect = False
    postreq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    Dim postData As String = "log=" & TextBox1.Text & "&pwd=" & TextBox2.Text & "&wp-submit=Log+In&redirect_to=" & cleanurl & "/wp-admin" & "&testcookie=1"
    Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
    Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)
    postreq.ContentLength = byteData.Length




    Dim postreqstream As Stream = postreq.GetRequestStream()
    postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
    postreqstream.Close()

    Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse
    postresponse = DirectCast(postreq.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)


    '/ The Following is set next request with authentication cookie

    Dim nextreq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(cleanurl), HttpWebRequest)
    nextreq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    nextreq.Method = "GET"
    nextreq.CookieContainer = New CookieContainer

    nextreq.CookieContainer.Add(postresponse.Cookies)


    nextreq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0b6pre) Gecko/20100903 Firefox/4.0b6pre"
    nextreq.KeepAlive = True

    Dim nextresponse As HttpWebResponse
    nextresponse = DirectCast(nextreq.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)

    logincookie = nextreq.CookieContainer
    logincookie.Add(nextresponse.Cookies)



    Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(nextresponse.GetResponseStream())
    Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd

    nextresponse.Close()

    RichTextBox1.Text = thepage
    WebBrowser1.DocumentText = thepage
    Refresh()

    If thepage.Contains("ERROR") Then
        MsgBox("Error logging in!")
    Else
        MsgBox("Lets Start Blogging!")

    End If
```

It works perfect, gets me to the URL homepage and shows me that Im logged in.
but when Im launching this code to get to the permalinks edit page it just returns the login page source code means it wasn't able to login.

```
Dim nextreq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(cleanurl & "/wp-admin/options-permalink.php"), HttpWebRequest)
    nextreq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    nextreq.Method = "GET"
    nextreq.CookieContainer = logincookie



    nextreq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0b6pre) Gecko/20100903 Firefox/4.0b6pre"
    nextreq.KeepAlive = True


    Dim nextresponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(nextreq.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)

    nextreq.CookieContainer.Add(nextresponse.Cookies)



    Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(nextresponse.GetResponseStream())
    Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd

    nextresponse.Close()

    RichTextBox1.Text = thepage
    WebBrowser1.DocumentText = thepage
    Refresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative. Try the Wordpress API (xmlrpc.php) to access and modify data in your Wordpress installation. I have used  CookComputing.XmlRpc to achieve this.

Here is a sample on how to create a new WordPress post:

```
Imports CookComputing.XmlRpc

Public Sub Add_New_Post_Sample()
    Dim NewPostContent As New NewPostContent
    NewPostContent.post_type = "post"
    NewPostContent.post_status = "draft"
    NewPostContent.post_title = "MyTitle"
    NewPostContent.post_author = "1"
    NewPostContent.post_excerpt = ""
    NewPostContent.post_content = "MyContent"
    NewPostContent.post_date_gmt = "2015-01-21 00:00:00"
    NewPostContent.post_name = "my-unique-url"
    NewPostContent.post_password = ""
    NewPostContent.comment_status = "closed"
    NewPostContent.ping_status = "closed"
    NewPostContent.sticky = False
    NewPostContent.post_thumbnail = 0
    NewPostContent.post_parent = 0
    NewPostContent.Mycustom_fields = New String() {""}

    Dim API = DirectCast(XmlRpcProxyGen.Create(GetType(IgetCatList)), IgetCatList)

    Dim clientprotocal = DirectCast(API, XmlRpcClientProtocol)
    clientprotocal.Url = "http://myurl.com/xmlrpc.php"

    Dim result As String = API.NewPost(1, "admin", "password", NewPostContent)

    Console.WriteLine(result)
End Sub

Public Structure NewPostContent
    Public post_type As String
    Public post_status As String
    Public post_title As String
    Public post_author As Integer
    Public post_excerpt As String
    Public post_content As String
    Public post_date_gmt As DateTime
    Public post_name As String
    Public post_password As String
    Public comment_status As String
    Public ping_status As String
    Public sticky As Boolean
    Public post_thumbnail As Integer
    Public post_parent As Integer
    Public Mycustom_fields As String()
End Structure
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for replying. I know this XMLRPC but I think it can only post articles and it is basically not what I need atm. I am looking to change permalink structure or deleting widjets and stuff like this. I don't think it is too hard I just have some problems with those cookies.

Comment: In that case why don't you just update the MySQL database directly? It will be easier to update the permalink directly but anyways check this link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411397/asp-net-to-wordpress-sso-with-httpwebrequest)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411397/asp-net-to-wordpress-sso-with-httpwebrequest)

From the link:


_The response was returning a system.net.cookie rather than a system.web.httpcookie. I created a new httpcookie using the data from the other cookie and it worked._

Comment: Not sure what did you mean, can we talk on skype or something to make it faster? Thanks!

Comment: I meant that you can query the MySQL database directly to retrieve and update data. You can query directly the wp_posts table from your .NET code. If you need to update the permalinks it will be much easier this way. To do this make sure you download the MySQL .NET Connector.

Comment: Regarding the cookies problem it seems the httpw‌​ebrequest method returns an object type sytem.net.cookie but accordingly to that other user you need to transform the object to a system.web.httpcoookie.

Comment: Well it is not only permalinks, I want it be possible to go to any options page editing any possible feature. About the cookie I haven't fully understand. Seriously this wordpress messed me up, they cookie care system is wierd, I tried alot but still seems not to understand how it works. I wish we can talk on skype or something to make it faster and post the answer here when we find the solution?